# Sharepoint 2010 windows authentication via login form (2 textboxes for username and password)

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

are there anyways to use a login form with a textbox for username and another one for password to authenticate a user with windows authentication ?

like the image below, i want to use a login form instead of the windows popup

i have a website with claim based authentication and i'm trying to do that, can anyone help me

?[image: screenshot]

Comment: i dig around for a while and was no clue. all the solutions was about fba with Active Directory as a provider.

Comment: Can you share any inside on why you what that scenario?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is possible but will require quite some work and deep knowledge about kerberos.

Reverse proxy solutions like Microsoft TMG are doing what you would like to do. It is possible to implement "some kind" of reverse proxy that will take the username and password from an ASPX page, store the data in "some" place and use the reverse proxy (Microsoft Application Request Routing) functions to fetch the authentication information and integrate them into the proxied request. This is a really bad solution.

If your portal is running on Kerberos Authentication (in a classic oder claims mode web app) and you are able to get all needed security configurations you can use the S4U services and do a protocol transition from plain text username and password to a real kerberos token. This will only work in intranet single domain environments. More details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649317.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650469.aspx

The best solution if you don't what traditional asp.net membership FBA of sharepoint you can switch to ADFS and use IDP login page:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895359.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895361.aspx

This will not excactly cover your requirments to stay on the SharePoint url but this is the simplest and cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication.aspx). It describes how to resolve your problem.

Comment: it looks helpful, but it only force the windows popup to show up like in the above image, i need to have  two textboxes where the user put username and password and a button to do the authentication, any suggestions ?

Comment: if I'm not wrong in the axample for this post you can find a custom page that is used for loggin. It looks like a page that you need. You only should change the markup.

Comment: nop. the login page appear after the user authenticated and for more security that page asks for PIN id.

Answer (score 0):

Your question describes what is more commonly called Forms Based Authentication or FBA.
Ironically, the page @Alexander links to has on it a link to a page about how to make a [custom FBA login page for Windows Authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).